# Can these steps for setting up Fedora for iommu single gpu passthrough be translated for Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: grub2, dracut

Long story short, I attempted to follow a guide on youtube, [Single GPU Passthrough Tutorial - KVM/VFIO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTWf5D092VY), and I'm running into difficulties when it concerns configuring linux on Ubuntu.

The guide seems fairly straight-forward for most of the steps, however, where it dives into changing the grub configuration and using dracut at around [5:10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTWf5D092VY&t=310s), the steps don't apply to Ubuntu.

Can this section of steps be translated to an equivalent for Ubuntu?

Edit: the steps outlined in the video for Fedora are as follows

1. Edit `/etc/sysconfig/grub` by adding `intel_iommu=on iommu=pt` or `amd_iommu=on iommu=pt` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` entry.
2. Apply changes to grub with command

   ```
   sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2.cfg
   ```
3. Add drivers to initramfs

   1. Create a new file: `/etc/dracut.conf.d/local.conf`
   2. Add a single line to this file:

      ```
      add_driver+=" vfio vfio_iommu_type1 vfio_pci vfio_virqfd "
      ```
   3. Apply the configuration using command (note: there are backticks surrounding `uname -r`)

      ```
      sudo dracut -f --kver `uname -r`
      ```

Comment: Please reproduce the actual steps here in the post.

Comment: @muru I added a summary of the steps in question.

Comment: For (1), you edit `/etc/default/grub`, and for (2) you need to run `sudo update-grub`. I'm not sure which file to edit for (3), but the command would be `sudo update-initramfs` once you have edited it. You can check the  manpages related to initramfs to see which file might be used instead